# How to deny ip address automatically by parsing nginx log file

Tags: nginx, dos, php

I have 4 webservers behind cloudflare and a loadbalancer, nginx is the webserver, php-fpm manages the php pages. I don't know how to block a simple dos attack ...

I'm able to detect this attack by using the http_limit_req module from nginx 
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule

but this is not blocking the attack at all, yes this can mitigate but webservers are hit and hit again, and php-fpm goes to 80% and in a minute the website is unreachable.

I'm trying to find a way to block this kind of request.

I know how to block certain ip address or certain useragent with nginx but i want to do it automatically. I think that I cannot block the ip with iptables because the request come from the loadbalancer :( but i'm still able to detect the correct ip address with the set_real_ip_from and real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For with nginx.

I have the log file (error.log) filled with the correct ip address as you can see:

2012/03/27 18:34:02 [error] 31234#0: *1283 limiting connections by zone "staging", client: XX.XX.XX.XXX, server: www.xxxxxxx.com, request: "HEAD /it HTTP/1.1", host: "www.xxxxxxx.com"

Someone have an idea and can teach me how to block automatically this ip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use fail2ban for this. It's a log-file parser for many different services which can detect failed logins, etc. and then block an IP-address.

http://www.fail2ban.org

Regards

Comment: yes i think this is a good solutions, i'm trying to setup fail2ban with this hint : http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,223078 i will let you know :) thanks

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with CSF instead of Fail2Ban?